# java exception - why does it catch?

Tags: java, exception

I've started studying exceptions in Java but I'don't uderstand why the output of this code is :

```
Throw SimpleException from f()
Cought it!
```

The code is this:

```
    class SimpleException extends Exception {}

    public class InheritingExceptions {
        public void f() throws SimpleException{
            System.out.println("Throw SimpleException from f()");
            throw new SimpleException();

        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            InheritingExceptions sed = new InheritingExceptions();
            try {
                sed.f();
            } catch (SimpleException e) {
                System.out.println("Cought it!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which part is confusing you? The method throws a `SimpleException`, and then your code catches it and prints Cought it.

Comment: In your method `f()`, you throw your own `SimpleException` at the very end. Your `try` block then `catch`es this exception and prints your message "Cought it!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your code is doing is:

1) Create a new InheritingExceptions object called sed

2) You wrap the sed.f() method with a try-catch block. The catch block is catching any SimpleException that is thrown within the try{}

3) sed invokes the method f() .
f() is doing the following:

- System.out.println("Throw SimpleException from f()"); -- This will print to the console "Throw SimpleException from f()"
- throw new SimpleException();

4) Since the f() method has thrown a SimpleException, your try-catch block catches it. When caught, it prints out to console "Cought it!"

```
class SimpleException extends Exception {}

public class InheritingExceptions {
    public void f() throws SimpleException{
        System.out.println("Throw SimpleException from f()");
        throw new SimpleException();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InheritingExceptions sed = new InheritingExceptions();
        try {
            sed.f();
        } catch (SimpleException e) {
            System.out.println("Cought it!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look, when you are doing this inside main:

```
sed.f();
```

You are calling that function and in that function f(), you are printing "Throw SimpleException from f()" and throwing an exception. And inside main you are catching that exception and printing "Cought it!"

Comment: so it catches whatever exception throwned of that type even if in the try block there aren't errors?

Comment: If you take a look inside function f() you will see that you are throwing an exception and of course the try-catch that you have inside main will catch the exception thrown by function f(). Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Because in `main()` method you have created an object of InheritingExceptions class
and using this object you are calling `f()` method of InheritingExceptions class.

as `f()` has printing **"Throw SimpleException from f()**" so you first output line will be this.
also `f()` is throwing SimpleException() , while calling `f()` from `main()` method you used `try-catch block` , this block will catch the exception thrown by `f()` method and code inside 
catch block will get executed this execution will print your second statement "**Cought it!!"**